# No rows returned

Tags: youtube-api

My youtube analytics API script works perfectly in the past, but suddenly doesn't work any more. The problem is the json returned does not contain rows fields

```
{
  'columnHeaders': [
    {
      'name': 'day', 
      'columnType': 'DIMENSION', 'dataType': 'STRING'
    }, 
    {
      'name': '...', 
      'columnType': 'METRIC', 'dataType': '...'
    }, ...
  ], 
  'kind': 'youtubeAnalytics#resultTable'
}
```

After googling, links below are very similar to my problem

- [youtube analytics api rows empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50647423/youtube-analytics-api-rows-empty)
- https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/youtube/e08jHBGtA_w/nksdr9S9AQAJ0
- https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/heVvzt4UqSs;context-place=topicsearchin/youtube/no$20data$20rows$20

However, either no answer or the solution provided doesn't work for me (my code already contains scope youtube.readonly ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/ytanalytics.readonly']).

Is there is any status page that I can check if it's a problem at google end or how to check any place that might go wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the file: "Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-..." located in my case at: ".\users\admin\appdata\roamming\YouTubeAnaltycis.Auth.Store"

Regards

Comment: Thanks but searching with `find . -name Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse\*` or `find . -type f -exec grep Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse\* {} \+` doesn't find any related string.

Comment: That is the name I used programming with C.net: "OAuthcredential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync( GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, new[] { YouTubeAnalyticsService.Scope.Youtube,YouTubeAnalyticsService.Scope.YtAnalyticsReadonly }, user, CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("YouTubeAnalytics.Auth.Store")).Result". Do you have a similar code?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can see in the [Reports: Query](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query) front page that you need to use the new scope:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly
```

instead of the old one:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly
```

After changing the scope, perform a re-authentication (delete the old credentials) for the new scope to take effect.

This is also confirmed in [this forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/youtube/e08jHBGtA_w/nksdr9S9AQAJ0).